# NSTextView keyDown Event

Tags: events, nstextfield, keydown, nstextview, first-responder

I want trigger the keyDown Event with every Key action. Therefore I have created a subclass of NSView.

```
@interface CodrTextView : NSView {
    NSTextField *lineNumberSpace;
    NSTextView *mainTextView;
}

- (id) initWithTextView:(NSTextView *)textView lineNumberSpace:(NSTextField *)textField;
```

I already have the method's:

```
- (id) initWithTextView:(NSTextView *)textView lineNumberSpace:(NSTextField *)textField {
   self = [self init];
   if (self){
       mainTextView = textView;
       lineNumberSpace = textField;
   }
   return self;
}

- (BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder {
   return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyView {
   return  YES;
}
```

My plan is to count the lines in the textView and write the numbers in the lineNumberSpace. I know that the methods work, because I have test it already with an IBAction on a button. This is the method:

```
- (long) getLineCount{
    NSString *content = [mainTextView string];
    NSUInteger numberOfLines, index, contentLength = [content length];
    for (index = 0, numberOfLines = 0; index < contentLength; numberOfLines++){
         index = NSMaxRange([content lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)]);
    }

    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [mainTextView layoutManager];
    NSUInteger numberOfGlyphs =[layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
    NSRange lineRange;
    for (numberOfLines = 0, index = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++){
         (void) [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index
                                           effectiveRange:&lineRange];
          index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    }
    numberOfLines++;
    return numberOfLines;
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {
     NSMutableString *lineNumberString = [NSMutableString string];
     long numberOfLines = [self getLineCount];

     for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfLines; i++){
         [lineNumberString appendString:([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d \n", i])];
     }
     [lineNumberSpace setStringValue:lineNumberString];
}
```

This method works surely. The problem is, with a button the number in the lineNumberSpace is changing correctly but with the keyDown Event it don't work. What is my mistake here?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint there in your "`keyDown:`" method, does the line that does "`setStringValue:`" hit in Xcode?

Comment: Thats the problem, i think something is wrong with the keyDown Event.

Comment: try this: if you set a breakpoint at the *beginning* of the "`keyDown:`" method (e.g. the line of code that creates the mutable string), does *that* hit when you do a keypress?

Comment: No it also don't break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, looking at your code I now realize what the problem is.

Your "`CodrTextView`" object is not subclassed from "`NSTextView`" (and also, when you instantiate the object programatically or via your XIB or Storyboard, make sure the text view object is a custom class of "`CodrTextView`" and not just another "`NSTextView`"), so it's not actually getting the "`acceptsFirstResponder`" or "`canBecomeKeyView`" method calls either.

You need to descend "`CodrTextView`" from "`NSTextView`" instead of "`NSView`", *OR* you need to create another subclassed "`NSTextView`" object which **will** receive the "`keyDown:`" event and then it'll call the code that calculates the string that goes into "`lineNumberSpace`" of your main view.

Does this make sense to you now?

Comment: Yes it makes sense for me. I changed the extended class in CodrTextView to "NSTextView" from "NSView". But it already don't break in the keyDown Event. What do you mean with: "make sure the text view object is a custom class of "CodrTextView" and not just another "NSTextView""? How can i  do this?

Comment: When you are typing into the text view, is it a "`NSTextView`" object or is it your "`CodrTextView`" object? How is that text view object created?

Comment: I put a `"NSScrollView"` with a `"NSTextView"` inside from the Object Library into the .xib File. I though the `"CodrTextView"` is created in the controller object with: `"mainTextView = [[CodrTextView alloc] initWithTextView:scriptView lineNumberSpace:lineNumbers];"`

Comment: Here's how I would fix this: you need to get rid of the "`NSScrollView`".  Drop a "`NSTextView`" into your xib file.  Change it's custom type to "`CodrTextView`".  ***This*** will allow you to receive "`keyDown:`" events.  You then need to figure out how to connect up the "`lineNumberSpace`" text field, because your "`CodrTextView`" needs to be instantiated from the XIB file and not created via "`initWithTextView:`".

Comment: Ok, tons of thanks for the help. I will try it. The only problem i see is that I need to scroll the textview.

Comment: When you create a textview via Xcode's Interface Builder, a scrollview is put in automatically for you.

Comment: Mhh, now it works with the breakpoints in the keyDown Method, but i can't write anything in the textview. And i can change the textview to an CodrTextView, but i can't get the TextView out of the Scroll View and there is no object with a NSTextView only.

Comment: Ok thats strange, if i delete the keyDown Event method and i write with normal letters in the TextView this come out: ||||||||||

Comment: Sorry, I'am really new in xCode programming.